# Bootstrap DropDown menu doesn't work after first click

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have my dropdown menu in my _Layout.cshtml and clicking on one of the menu items works fine the first time, for example takes me to http://localhost:52098/Home/ViewTable/Scottish Premiership.

If I click on the URL again, it tries taking me to http://localhost:52098/Home/ViewTable/Home/ViewTable/Scottish Premiership

The navigation Code:

```
div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                        Scotland <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu">
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="Home/ViewTable/Scottish Premiership">
                                Scottish Premiership
                            </a></li>
                            <li role="presentation">
                                <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="Home/ViewMain/Scottish Championship">
                                    Scottish Championship
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li role="presentation">
                                <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">
                                   Scottish First Division
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li role="presentation">
                                <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">
                                   Scottish Second Division
                                </a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
               </li>
                <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                        England <span class="caret"></span>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li role="presentation">
                                <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="Home/ViewMain/Scottish Championship">
                                   English Premier League
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li role="presentation">
                                <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="Home/ViewMain/Scottish Championship">
                                   English Championship
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
           // @*@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(false, true, true, true, true)
            @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()*@


            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav"></ul>
            </div>

</div>
```

Looks like it's taking a relative path from the one i'm already on + the href on the link, where as what I really want is an absolute path?

Comment: Add '/' to the start of Your URLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add '/' to the start of your URLs

like `/Home/ViewMain/Scottish ChampionShip`

And it is always better to use

```
@Url.Action("MethodName", "Controller")
```

e.g.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("MethodName", "Controller")"> Test</a>
```

To pass a Parameter in URL

```
  <a href="@Url.Action("MethodName", "Controller", new {LeagueName = "Scottish Premiership"})"> Test</a>
```

Comment: Ah yes, that was a bit of a rookie mistake. I've not done a huge amount of work using htmlhelper etc and I did think about having ActionLinks etc, but wasn't 100% sure how to do it within the href tag so thanks for that :)

Comment: I'm having a similar problem though I've been using link_to:

<li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Conditions & Treatments <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to 'Achilles Tendinitis, Tendinosis', conditions_achilles_path %></li>
           
I'm not sure why but the @Url.Action way mentioned says that there is no path so is that something I have to state somewhere else first? Sorry, still a newbie here.