# Bootstrap dropdown still doesn't work after first click (link_to version)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I saw there was a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28965090/bootstrap-dropdown-menu-doesnt-work-after-first-click) but it didn't quite answer my question's version. I'm still new to Rails so I know this must be a simple reason behind the logic.

I don't know how to adapt Bootstrap with rails routes; It keeps adding a # to the end of my links but I'm not sure how to prevent this but still enable the dropdown.

```html
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Conditions & Treatments <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><%= link_to 'Achilles Tendinitis, Tendinosis', conditions_achilles_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Arthritis, Hallus Limitus, Hallux Rigidus', conditions_arthritis_path %></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

If someone could explain what I'm sure is a simple logic that would be great, thank you.

Comment: Apart from the `#` (you made me realize I had the same weird thing happening on my app), do you have any problem ? Even thought I have this `#` the links are still working

Comment: The issue is that I can't get the dropdown to show up when I click on the dropdown menu. If it did dropdown, maybe the links would work, but I can't get it to even dropdown after I click on it the second time.

Comment: If you are using turbolinks, disable it and try again.

Comment: Maybe the issue is more subtle than that. Have you included `//= require bootstrap` to your **application.js**? This would include Bootstrap's javascript library, necessary for the dropdown to work

Comment: @Loqman's suggestion worked, thank you! I wonder why that is? I need to read into it, but thank you all the same!

Comment: @TimKos When I tried to add the require bootstrap it says that it's missing the file. Also, the dropdown does work the first time I try it, but once I click to another page/link, the dropdown fails to work again.

Comment: Are you using a bootstrap gem by any chance? make sure you have `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.0'` inside your Gemfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turbolinks can conflict with the behavior of your application's javascript, and it's up to you to fix it. This is pretty easy to do with the code you've written, but when the problem lies within a third-party library or plug-in, identifying and resolving the conflict can become much more frustrating.

Some common causes for these conflicts include:

- Initialization bound to the DOM Ready event
- Initialization code loading external scripts and appending elements to the document's `head`
- The use of global variables on the `window` object.

Turbolinks encourages you to put your JavaScript in the `<head>` so the JS is not executed each time the `<body>` is replaced.

You can place JS at the bottom of the page and still get your code to work. The code has to clean up the previous state of the page, reinitialize, and not always rely on `document.ready`. To enable Tooltips for example:

```
// Cleanup + enable Bootstrap tooltips on jQuery's ready event as well as
// Turbolinks's page change event.
$(document).on("ready page:change", function() {
  $("[data-toggle='tooltip']")
    .tooltip("destroy")
    .tooltip();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem. I had a dropdown which works but only for the first click. After the page refreshed it no longer worked.

I followed what Loqman said, to place the  element in the head and not in the body.
I moved this piece of code to be in the head:

```
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Just by doing that my dropdown works properly now.
I am using bootstrap 5 and rails 7.